# WCF can not read XML

Tags: xml, wcf, rest

I received an XML value from android.

on my .NET I have coded:

```
 try
            {
                var reader = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                 Result +=   reader.ReadString();
                }
```

but i got error

> Character not attended '<'

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

**GetReaderAtBodyContents** returns **XmlDictionaryReader**.
Could you look that-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708681/1923256